# Accessing components of deleted object

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have a trigger that inserts records deleted/updated from table A into table B.Which is achieved by use of a deleted object in sql server.
My question is.Is there a way that I can be able to determine if an action performed in table A is an update or deleted using the deleted object in sql server

Comment: easy way is to use separate trigger. One for `UPDATE` and another for `DELETE`. Or check for existence of records in `inserted`. For `DELETE`, there will not be anything in `inserted`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example...

```
drop table if exists dbo.temp;
drop table if exists dbo.log;
go

create table dbo.temp(Id int, Value varchar(100));
insert dbo.temp values (1, '1'), (2, '2'), (3, '3');
go

create table dbo.log(Id int, Operation char(1));
go

create trigger trigger_temp
    on dbo.temp
    for update, delete
as begin

    insert dbo.Log
    select  i.Id , 'U'
    from    inserted i
    inner join deleted d
            on d.Id = i.Id;

    insert dbo.Log
    select  d.Id, 'D'
    from    deleted  d
    left outer join inserted i
            on i.Id = d.Id
    where   i.Id is null

end;
go

insert dbo.temp values (4, '4');
update dbo.temp set Value = '-1' where Id = 1;
delete dbo.temp where id = 2;
select * from dbo.Log
go
```